# Generating JNI Wrappers from GDCM Library

Tags: java, c++, dicom, gdcm

I am trying to get JNI Wrapper classes by use of SWIG tool. but I m very beginner in C++ Library Compilation etc..

I have downloaded CMake Tool . SWIG but dont know how to utilize them and create Java Wrappers from the source folders. If any body have experience with this please share it as GDCM library does not have such good step by step documentation about it.

Currenly I have downloaded Source Code. and have following structure please give me some hint how to start compiling JNI Classes from these source .

[image: GDCM Source Structure]

**Note :** I am on Windows Machine.

Answer (score 0):

Simply follow instructions for [C# bindings](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Configuring_and_Building_With_VS_.NET_2008_%28Include_C_sharp_wrapping%29). Instead of having GDCM_WRAP_CSHARP=ON, set GDCM_WRAP_JAVA to ON.